# Variable concurrency in Singleton Class pattern

Tags: java, singleton, hashtable, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

I was trying to write a singleton class, which will be used for simple cache implementation. I followed a **double checked locking** pattern for getting the instance where the instance is a volatile member inside the class. It also contains a **HashTable** for storing the data.

If I am trying to access a value inside the map through a method, should I provide 'synchronized' keyword for blocking concurrent access?. I am asking this question because the UserCache itself is **syncronized** using double-checked-locking in the getInstance() method

Or is it better to use a **ConcurrentHashMap** instead of **HashTable**?

See the code snippet below for more details.

```
public class UserCache {

private volatile static UserCache instance;
private Hashtable<String, User> users = null;

private UserCache() {
    this.users = new Hashtable<String, User>();
}

public static UserCache getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (UserCache.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new UserCache();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public synchronized User getUser(String userUid) {
    return this.users.get(userUid);
}

public synchronized boolean addUser(User user) {

    if (isValidUser(user.getUserUid())) {

        return false;
    }
    this.users.put(user.getUserUid(), user);

    return true;
}

...
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: better use a concurrent hash map because synchronized won't help you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the extent of your class, then a ConcurrentHashMap would work. If you have any additional methods where more than a simple get/put to the map needs to be synchronized, a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) is a good option to allow concurrent reads.

Another alternative to your double checked locking with a volatile static would be to use an inner class:

```
private static final class DeferredLoader {
    static final UserCache INSTANCE = new UserCache();
}

public static UserCache getInstance() {
    return DeferredLoader.INSTANCE;
}
```

This has the advantage of being immutable and still defers the creation of the instance until the getInstance method is called the first time.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Brett Okken. I am going to use a concurrent hashmap

Answer (score 0):

If your methods are synchronized I don't see the need for ConcurrentHashMap. Still, I would use Map<,> instead of Hashtable. It's good practice to favor interfaces.